# PL SQL - convert a numerical value into varchar (percent)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a query that uses the outputs(R1,R2) of two sub queries in order to divide them:

```
select a.R1/b.R2*100.0 as Result
from
(query1) a,
(query2) b
```

The division's output is a (decimal) number as well as the R1,R2 outputs.

I want to add to the Result the '%' sign, (i.e 10,75 %), but using a solution like the below one, returns an error 01722=invalid number

```
select cast(cast(a.R1/b.R2*100.0 as decimal(10,2)) as varchar(10)) + '%' as Result
from
(query1) a,
(query2) b
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome!

Replace the addition operator **'+'** with the SQL-Pl/sql concatenation operator:  '**||**'.

We **can't** use character literals **directly** in **number format models** like in Datetime conversion.

[SQL Concatenation operator](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/operators003.htm#SQLRF51158)

[PL/SQL Concatenation operator](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/fundamentals.htm#CIHHHEJG)

[Number format models](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements004.htm#i34570)

---

Examples:

```
select cast(round(10.75, 2) as varchar(10)) || '%' as result
from   dual

select to_char(round(1234567890.29, 2),'9G999G999G999D99' ) || '%' as result
from   dual
```

---

**PS.**
The route is always the same:

**[How to ask](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before)**

**[All the "oracles" are here:](http://tahiti.oracle.com)**